# How to determine if a struct can be constructed from a given initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, initializer-list

In an effort to make life a bit easier when solving a complicated PDE system, I am writing a C++ wrapper around (the relevant portion of) a C numerical library. When dealing with multiple unknowns, the library just assigns an array to each grid point and pass its pointer to your user-specified function. The user could refer to each unknown via F[0], F[1], ...

Of course, these unknowns usually have proper mathematical names, and it would be nice to be able to refer to them as such. An obvious solution is to define a `struct` like

```
template <typename T>
struct unknowns
{
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;
    T d;
};
```

and convert the `double*` to `unknowns<double>*` using `reinterpret_cast`. This does seem to work, however after reading [Can I treat a struct like an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967275/can-i-treat-a-struct-like-an-array) I have been trying to find a better solution that guarantees correctness in this conversion process (and also gracefully dealing with non-scalar `T` -- something that I might need a bit later).

The second most obvious solution, then, is to redefine `vars` so that it holds `T&` instead, and then concoct up something like the following

```
template <size_t DOF>
class factory
{
private:

    template <template <typename> class Target, typename T, typename... Index>
    static typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Index) < DOF), Target<T>>::type
    _do_construct(T* array, Index... index)
    {
        return _do_construct<Target>(array, index..., sizeof...(Index));
    }   

    template <template <typename> class Target, typename T, typename... Index>
    static typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(Index) == DOF, Target<T>>::type
    _do_construct(T* array, Index... index)
    {
        return { array[index]... };
    }

public:

    template <template <typename> class Target, typename T>
    static Target<T> wrap_array(T* array)
    {
        return _do_construct<Target>(array);
    }
};
```

With this, I can now convert a library-provided `double* f` to an `unknowns<double> F` safely via

```
    auto F = factory<4>::wrap_array<unknowns>(f);
```

which is rather nice.

What would be even better now is if I could also omit the `<4>`, however I couldn't figure out how to do this. Presumably it should be possible to use SFINAE to determine how many members the struct holds, but `std::is_constructible` doesn't seem to be able to do what I need.

Could anyone suggest how this might be possible?

Comment: side-note: within a year time we're supposed to get concepts lite to solve this problem

Comment: How do you want to omit the "4"? Who else on that line knows the value "4"?

Comment: @Kerrek SB In this case, since `unknowns` have four members, it can only constructed from an initializer list with precisely 4 members. Anything else would fail. Surely there is a way to exploit this and have the compiler deduce the `<4>` automatically?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Interesting...

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. Back then, I defined an enum, holding the mathematical names. For example `enum { X, Y, Z, SIZE};` and then given an array `v` I would type `v[Y]` instead of `v[1]`, etc. I am curious what answers you get, up voted your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to determine at compiletime the number of members
in a template `struct Target<typename T>`, where `Target` is
a POD `struct` template whose members are only known to consist 0 or more `T`'s, 
and where `T` for your immediate needs is `double`.

You would like a solution that is consistent with `T` being not even a scalar.

This can be solved, with one minor limition, by exploiting the fact:
that `struct Target<T>` cannot have more members than `sizeof(Target<T>)`. It is
true that a `struct X` containing bitfields could have more members that
`sizeof(X)`, but the *type* of a bitfield is `{unsigned|signed} int`,
so the statement holds for `struct Target<T>`, for any `T`.

The minor limitation is that `T` be default constructible.

Since `sizeof(Target<T>)` is a compiletime upper limit for the number of fields
in `Target<T>`, we can write a *recursive-SFINAE* solution. 
Compiletime recursion is driven down from that limit by substitution failure
based upon the unsatisfiable type of an expression that attempts to
initialize a `Target<T>` with *too many initializers* of type T: until the
substitution does not fail, and then - thanks to the POD character of `Target<T>` -
we know that the number of its fields is the length of the initializer
list that it has finally accepted. We need not care with what values these
speculative initializations are attempted, provided the values are of a
type convertible to T.

(We cannot, of course, just recurse *up* from 0 initalizers, because `Target<T>`
will accept any initializer list that is *not* too long.)

To implement such a solution we need a compiletime means of generating initializer
lists of a type `I` of arbitrary length, where `I` is convertible to `T`. If
`I` could be an integral type, then various examples of prior art for
*compiletime generation of integer sequences* would spring to mind (including
examples from SO C++ luminaries: 
[Shaub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/1362568),[Wakeley](http://gitorious.org/redistd/redistd/blobs/master/include/redi/index_tuple.h),
[Kühll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059084/1362568)).

The snag with this line-of-low-resistance is the constraint it apparently
entails that `T` be constructible from an *integral* type `I`. That would not
rule out a non-scalar `T`, but it would very footlingly narrow the field.

The snag is only apparent, however. Since we will not care what `T`s compose
our speculative initializer lists, they might as well all be same `T`, and
if we stipulate only that `T` be default-constructible, there will be no
difficulty in turning out identical ones. Then to build these initializer lists
we do not actually need `T` to be constructible from an integral type `I`. 
We just need `T` to be constructible from some intermediate type `S` that is 
constructible from that `I`. And we can simply *create* such an `S` from a 
template, say, `shim<U>`, for `U = T`, with the desired properties that `shim<U>(I)` 
is a constructor and `shim<U> operator T() const` returns `U()`.

So far so good. But is a solution of greater generality now on the cards?

We have in view a way of finding the maximum length of intializer-list-of-`T`
that `Target<T>` will accept, and can thus infer the number of fields in the
template `Target` given our preconditions on its character. Suppose we
waived those preconditions: that `Target` is a template `Target<T>`; that
all its fields are of type `T`; that it is POD.

We would then still have in view a compiletine method of determining
whether any type `Target` is capable of being constructed with any initializer-list-of-`T`
of length <= an arbitrary limit `M`. This is likely to be more useful than 
the preliminary idea (though still recheche enough).

A trivial cost of this extra generality would be that the interface of the 
template solution can no longer be parameterized simply by `Target` and `T` 
whenever `Target` *is* a template on `T`, per your problem. In that case it will
have to be parameterized by  `Target<T>` and `T`. A more important penalty 
would be the fact that we would now need additionally to parameterize the 
template interface with that `M` = the limiting length within which a 
initializer list for `Target` shall be sought. Why? Because if `Target` is not 
POD, then `sizeof(Target)` is no longer an upper bound on the number 
of initializers that `Target` might accept.

The need for such an `M` was just what you didn't like about your own solution. 
But the more general solution can still avoid the need for it whenever 
`Target` *is* POD. Since that property is detectable by 
`std::is_pod<Target>::value == true`, the more general solution can default `M` 
in that case to `sizeof(Target)` and otherwise not default it at all.

The following solution is the residue of all this. For my compiletime-integer-sequences 
apparatus I have chosen to plagiarize C++ standards committee member 
[Daniel Krügler](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/H6icuxL0NAY),

**make_indices.h**

```
#ifndef MAKE_INDICES_H
#define MAKE_INDICES_H

/* After [Daniel Krügler]
    https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/H6icuxL0NAY

*/  
template<unsigned...> struct indices {}; 

namespace detail {

template<unsigned I, class Indices, unsigned N> 
struct make_indices; 

template<unsigned I, unsigned... Indices, unsigned N> 
struct make_indices<I, indices<Indices...>, N> 
{ 
    typedef typename make_indices<I + 1, indices<Indices..., I>, N>::type type; 
}; 

template<unsigned N, unsigned... Indices> 
struct make_indices<N, indices<Indices...>, N> 
{ 
    typedef indices<Indices...> type; 
};

} // namespace detail 

template<unsigned N> 
struct make_indices : detail::make_indices<0, indices<>, N> {}; 

#endif // EOF
```

Then my contribition: **initializer_count.h**

```
#ifndef INITIALIZER_COUNT_H
#define INITIALIZER_COUNT_H

#include "make_indices.h"
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {

/* class detail::shim<U> is a convenience wrapper of U whose
    sole purpose is to be constructible from unsigned and
    convertible to a U.
*/  
template<typename U>
struct shim
{
    static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<U>::value,
        "U must be default-constructible for detail::shim<U>");
    explicit shim(unsigned){};
    operator U () const {
        return U();
    }
};

} // namespace detail

/*
    class initializer_count<Target,T> will export 
    `static const unsigned value` == the maximum length <= Size of
    initializer list of T that Target will accept. 

    Size defaults to sizeof(Target) if Target id POD. Otherwise a static_assert
    is tripped if Size is defaulted.
*/
template<
    class Target, 
    typename T, 
    unsigned Size = std::is_pod<Target>::value ? sizeof(Target) : unsigned(-1)
>
struct initializer_count;

// Terminal case
template<class Target, typename T>
struct initializer_count<Target,T,0>
{
    static const unsigned value = 0;
};

// Recursion case.
template<class Target, typename T, unsigned Size>
struct initializer_count
{
    static_assert(Size != unsigned(-1),
        "Size cannot be defaulted for non-POD "
        "Target in initializer_count<Target,T,Size>");

    // SFINAE success. Target can be initialized with a list of length Size 
    template<unsigned ...I>
    static constexpr auto count(indices<I...>) -> 
            decltype(Target{detail::shim<T>(I)...},Size) {
        return Size;
    }

    // SFINAE failure.
    template<unsigned ...I>
    static constexpr unsigned count(...) {
        // Recurse to Size - 1
        return initializer_count<Target,T,Size - 1>::value;
    }

    static const unsigned value = count(typename make_indices<Size>::type());
};

#endif // EOF
```

A test program (gcc 4.7.2/4.8.1, clang 3.2):

```
#include "initializer_count.h"

struct non_pod 
{
    non_pod(){}
    non_pod(double a, short b)
    : _a(a),_b(b){}
    double _a = 42.0;
    short _b = 42;
};

template <typename T>
struct five_unknowns
{
    T a;
    T b;
    T c;
    T d;
    T e;
};

template <typename T>
struct one_unknown
{
    T a;
};

template <typename T>
struct zero_unknowns {};

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static const unsigned initializer_max = 100;
    static_assert(!std::is_pod<non_pod>::value,"");
    cout << initializer_count<zero_unknowns<char>,char>::value << endl;
    cout << initializer_count<one_unknown<int>,int>::value << endl;
    cout << initializer_count<five_unknowns<double>,double>::value << endl;
    // Need initializer_max for rest non-pod targets...
    cout << 
        initializer_count<five_unknowns<non_pod>,non_pod,initializer_max>::value
        << endl;
    cout << initializer_count<non_pod,short,initializer_max>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}

// EOF
```

Expected output:

```
0
1
5
5
2
```

Comment: I ended up writing something very similar to this myself but the compiler wouldn't take it. I haven't quite figured out exactly what is the difference between your solution and mine, but I think it might come down to the relative lack of C++11 support in Intel. Will report back when I figure out more. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How about another wrapper:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
Target<T> wrap_actual_array(T const (&a)[N])
{
    return factory<N>::wrap_array<unkowns>(a);
}
```