# Portable way to create heterogenous vertex data array

Tags: c++, c, portability, memory-alignment, structure-packing

It is very common in graphics programming to work with vertex formats.
This is described, for example, [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Interleaved_attributes).

However, I am looking for a way to accomplish that which does not invoke undefined behavior
(I'm mainly looking for C++ info, but C would be fine, too).

The common way to do it is like this: First, declare your vertex format as a struct.

```
struct Vertex {
    float x;
    float y;
    uint16_t someData;
    float etc;
};
```

Then, you create an array of these, fill them in, and send them to your graphics API (eg: OpenGL).

```
Vertex myVerts[100];
myVerts[0].x = 42.0;
// etc.

// when done, send the data along:
graphicsApi_CreateVertexBuffer(&myVerts[0], ...);
```

(Aside: I skipped the part where you tell the API what the format is; we'll just assume it knows).

However, the graphics API has no knowledge about your struct. It just wants a sequence of values in memory, something like:

```
|<---  first vertex   -->||<---  second vertex  -->| ...
[float][float][u16][float][float][float][u16][float] ...
```

And thanks to issues of packing and alignment, there is no guarantee that `myVerts` will be laid out that way in memory.

Of course, tons of code is written this way, and it works, despite [not being portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967275/can-i-treat-a-struct-like-an-array).

But is there *any* portable way to do this that is not either

```
1. Inefficient
2. Awkward to write
```

?

This is basically a serialization problem. See also: [Correct, portable way to interpret buffer as a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165134/correct-portable-way-to-interpret-buffer-as-a-struct)

The main standards-compliant way I know of is to allocate your memory as `char[]`.
Then, you just fill in all the bytes exactly how you want them laid out.

But to transform from the `struct Vertex` representation above to that `char[]` representation would require an extra copy (and a slow byte-by-byte one, at that). So that's inefficient.

Alternatively, you could write data into the `char[]` representation directly, but that's extremely awkward. It's much nicer to say `verts[5].x = 3.0f` than addressing into a byte array, writing a float as 4 bytes, etc.

Is there a good, portable way to do this?

Comment: No, of course not, since for example the binary representation of floating point numbers differs largely between platforms. Either restrict the platform portability or use marshalling/unmarshalling functions, which convert between the formats and operates on character level.

Comment: AFAIK, OpenGL API allows you to specify both the size of the vertex element and the offset and kind of each field in a structure.

Comment: You could have the data in your struct in a `char[]` of the right size and expose some methods to read from/write to the different members you would want it to have. This would sadly involve a lot of boilerplate. But if you want to the struct to have a contiguous memory layout, to the best of my knowledge having an underlying `char[]` is the only way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, the graphics API has no knowledge about your struct. It just wants a sequence of values in memory, something like:
>
> ```
> |<---  first vertex   -->||<---  second vertex  -->| ...
> [float][float][u16][float][float][float][u16][float] ...
> ```

This is not true. The graphics API has knowledge about your struct, because you told it about your struct. You even know this already:

> (Aside: I skipped the part where you tell the API what the format is; we'll just assume it knows).

When you tell the graphics API where each field is in your struct, you should use `sizeof` and `offsetof` instead of guessing the layout of your struct. Then your code will work even if the compiler inserts padding. For example (in OpenGL):

```
struct Vertex {
    float position[2];
    uint16_t someData;
    float etc;
};

glVertexAttribPointer(position_index, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct Vertex), (void*)offsetof(struct Vertex, position));
glVertexAttribIPointer(someData_index, 1, GL_SHORT, sizeof(struct Vertex), (void*)offsetof(struct Vertex, someData));
glVertexAttribPointer(etc_index, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(struct Vertex), (void*)offsetof(struct Vertex, etc));
```

*not*

```
glVertexAttribPointer(position_index, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14, (void*)0);
glVertexAttribIPointer(someData_index, 1, GL_SHORT, 14, (void*)8);
glVertexAttribPointer(etc_index, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 14, (void*)10);
```

Of course, if you were reading your vertices from disk as a blob of bytes in a known format (which could be different from the compiler's struct layout), then you may use a hardcoded layout to interpret those bytes. If you're treating vertices as an array of structs, then use the layout the compiler has decided for you.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. However, are you saying that it *is* portable/defined behavior to have an array of `struct Vertex`, and, using the information gleaned from `sizeof` and `offsetof`, then read out specific values from that array, interpreting them in certain ways?  In other words: is this still undefined, but we're kicking the can over to OpenGL, which has presumably provided a platform-appropriate solution? That is: If I controlled both ends of this serialization, could I write portable code (eg: send on one machine, receive on another)?

Comment: @jwd Is there a reason you expect this to be undefined?

Comment: Not especially, but that's the tricky thing about UB — it happens by default, if it's not explicitly allowed by the standard. So, I'm just wondering if the approach we're discussing *is* explicitly supported. It could be Undefined Behavior, Unspecified Behavior, or Implementation-defined behavior (none of which are portable). Or, it could be that holy grail of "well-defined behavior", which is what I'm striving for  (: